# Is there a standard case for POST parameters?

Tags: http, post

As the topic says, is there a standard, or a common way to write out the POST parameters?
Should I use camelCase, hyphens or some other way? For example, which one would be preferred, `use-template` vs `useTemplate`? Are there any technical reasons to favor one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no is standard case for POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no "standard case" for POST parameters, the recommendation is to be consistent with the rest of your code base.